# Warehouse Expansion: Is a new fire pump and tank required

Tags: fire-sprinkler

For an existing Warehouse, with sprinkler system already installed:
We are adding 3 mezzanine floors, with around 27000 Sq. ft for each floor. While designing sprinkler system, is it necessary to add new Fire tanks, Fire pumps for sprinkler system once again or can we connect the sprinkler riser to the existing system. We are also adding around 12 Fire house box(3 per floor) which will be connected to the ring main. Is it okay?

Comment: This you need to check with the fire authorities - but the flow rate and storage capacity has to meet the standards - if you are increasing the floor area by a factor of 3 then the tanks etc also need to increase...

Answer (score -1):

Are you adding the addition without any permits?

Because not only you need to get approval from the fire-department for adding new tanks and fire pipes and Siamese connection, you need to meet all the new fire exits, signage, fire partitions, etc. Guess what your insurance company will say in case of a claim.

You need to get the structure checked for additional loading, electrical panels, and circuits, lighting, and airconditioning. handicap access, basically you have a substantial job and have to get it permitted.

Comment: We will get the permits for the same. But is a new tank and pump required? Isnt the fire tank and pump already designed for a certain area(Using the sample area/density curve). Calculations mentioned below :

Comment: SPRINKLER SYSTEM 
Accordance with NFPA 13. Maximum hazard 1500sq.feet will be occur in Ordinary hazard 
Sprinkler spacing will be 3.6 meters
design density will be 0.15gpm/ft2
1500 x 0.15 = 225 gpm 
Total capacity will be 225gpm... 
Residual Pressure required at Sprinkler      = 3.5 Bar
 
Pressure loss in pipe/fittings etc  = 0.5 bar
Safety                                       = 0.5 bar
 
Total head pressure required       = 4.5bar Minimum.

Comment: Accordance with NFPA 13.   
Wet Riser(Landing Valve)  Flow rate   = 250 gpm   
Max No of WR in operation at any time  = 1 No   
Pump flow rate required                       = 1 x 250 gpm = 250 gpm   
Fire hose reel pump Head calculation   
Residual Pressure required at WR      = 4.5 Bar   
    
Pressure loss in pipe/fittings etc  = 1.5 bar (assumed, larger length of pipe needs more pressure)   
Safety                                       = 0.5 bar   
    
Total head pressure required       = 6.5 bar Minimum.

Comment: Above calculations are for 1) Sprinkler 2) Fire Hose reel

Comment: @Designer The comment block is just for "comment", not work, nor area for problem statement. You shall modify your question to include the existing capacity, the required capacity per your understanding, then ask for confirmation, or additional concerns. I don't think the existing system has considered the addition unless it was stipulated in the original design document, which you shall dig out for reference use.